# "Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients." during crontab

Tags: python, cron, pynput

I created a Python script with pynput which I want to run with a crontab. The script needs access to input monitoring.

In "Security & Privacy" I added the Python version which I use in my crontab. I copied the path from my crontab into the Finder Go to Folder function `Finder > Go > Go to Folder... > /usr/local/bin/python3.10` and drag and dropped the Python version in the input monitoring field. In my `backup.log` file from cron I still can see the error message `This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.` and the script is not working.

**Input Monitoring**

[image]

**Crontab**

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.10  /Users/username/Projects2022/ShortcutManager/shortcuts.py > /Users/username/backup.log 2>&1`

**Error von backup.log**

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The error message `This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.` was not the reason why my script didn't worked. The problem was that I didn't checked cron in the Accessibility section.

**Cron needs to to be checked**

[image]